# How to get serverCallId to to initiate call recording in MS Teams?

Tags: api, web-applications, microsoft-teams, call-recording, azure-communication-services

I'm building an angular web application. Finding for an API to start recording in MS teams. I referred [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/communication/callautomation/server-calls/start-recording).

How to get `serverCallId`?

Comment: I am checking if I can get you some reference and trying to get the info internally.

Answer (score 0):

To get the serverCallId you can refer this doc - [Getting server call Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/call-recording-sample?pivots=programming-language-java#getting-servercallid-as-a-requirement-for-call-recording-server-apis), however it doesn't start or support recording Teams meeting with this API.

Please have a look at this **Note** as well-
[image]